socat to fork interactive sessions to support reverse shell
I want to use socat to fork multiple screeen/tmux sessions which accept reverse shell from nc. Let's say socat listens on 5555.
I used many approaches, one of them:
#!/bin/bash

# Use socat to listen on port 5555 and handle connections
socat TCP-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"/bin/bash -c 'screen -dmS socat_session_$SOCAT_PEERADDR bash -i'"

When connecting with nc.traditional localhost 4444, it disconnects immidiately.
